# Inherited sprite not draw-able

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, sfml

In SFML I wanted to have a sprite but with other functions and variables so i decided to create a class that inherits the sprite class like this:
1. Player.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class Player : sf::Sprite{
    public:
        void setup();
        void input();
    private:
        int direction;
        void moveRight();
        void moveLeft();
        sf::Texture textures[8];
};
```

2(WIP). Player.cpp

```
void Player::setup(){
    direction = 0;
    textures[0].loadFromFile("images/player_right_still.png");
    textures[1].loadFromFile("images/player_right_jump.png");
    textures[2].loadFromFile("images/player_right_walk1.png");
    textures[3].loadFromFile("images/player_right_walk2.png");
    textures[4].loadFromFile("images/player_left_still.png");
    textures[5].loadFromFile("images/player_left_jump.png");
    textures[6].loadFromFile("images/player_left_walk1.png");
    setTexture(textures[0]);
}

void Player::input(){
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right) || sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D)){
        moveRight();
    }
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left) || sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A)){
        moveLeft();
    }
}

void Player::moveRight(){

}

void Player::moveLeft(){

}
```

3. game.cpp (picture because SO is being weird on me)
   [image: game.cpp]

But when I compile it I get this error:

```
game.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
game.cpp:23:27: error: ‘sf::Drawable’ is an inaccessible base of ‘Player’
         window.draw(player);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`class Player : sf::Sprite` means that inheritance is private, that is code using instances of `Player` class won't be able to cast it to `Sprite` or access methods inherited from `Sprite` class. You should change inheritance to `public`:

```
class Player: public sf::Sprite
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I've been stuck on this for days!